# How to add paragraph between two images in css

Tags: html, css

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zrqx5e34/

I have been created simple rounded images, now i want to add paragraph between two images,

Need to shows right side of between the images.

May i know how to do this? Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

http://s9.postimg.org/uloaz1mnj/Untitled_1.png

css:

```
.circular {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 150px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 150px;
    -moz-border-radius: 150px;
    background: url('img/saina1.png') no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    margin-bottom: 130px;
    position: relative;
    }
.circular:after {
    background-color: green;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 128px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100px;
    width: 2px;
    left: 50px;
}
.circular:first-child:after {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Do you have a design image of the expected final result?

Comment: @Paulie_D:.. i need something like this http://s12.postimg.org/r641c27q5/Untitled_1.png

Comment: Then you would need to restructure the HTML. You need a wrapper for each 'event' which would contain the text **and** the 'circular' div. Perhaps something like [**this**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jIGlA)

Comment: @sona try tis one http://jsfiddle.net/zrqx5e34/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zrqx5e34/2/)**

As you are limiting the circular class width, its not possible to show beyond that while placing text inside it. So we can achieve something like this only

**CSS:**

```
.circular > p{
    margin-top:90px;
    margin-left:70px;
    float:left;
    height:128px;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is similar to timeleine.. Hope here you can get what you want http://bashooka.com/coding/css-timeline-tutorials-examples/

Comment: may i know... what is the mean timeline?

Comment: see the jd fiddle : i have made two whoever is your requirement : http://jsfiddle.net/zrqx5e34/3/   and   http://jsfiddle.net/zrqx5e34/6/

Comment: @sona: Pl be clear & precise while asking your question, don't change it again & again